# Why are principal components in PCA linear combinations of input vectors?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

In Principal Components Analysis (PCA), one gets to the following equation:

$$\psi_l = \frac{1}{\lambda_lN}\sum_{i=1}^n \langle \mathbf{x}_i,\psi_l\rangle\mathbf{x}_i$$

where $(\lambda, \psi)_l$ is an eigenvalue-eigenvector pair, $\mathbf{x}_i$ is the i-th observation of the data and $\langle \cdot \rangle$ denotes the scalar product.

From this equation it is said without any further explanation that $\psi_l$ is a linear combination of the input vectors, i.e.:

$$\psi_l = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_{il} \mathbf{x}_i$$

but this is really mysterious: how can it be a linear combination if the right hand has it as a term?

Comment: It is a linear combination of the input vectors in that it's a sum of scalar multiples of them. It happens to be that the scalars are equal to inner products of the left hand vector with the input vectors.

Comment: So for vectors it is still a linear combination even if the coefficients depend themselves on the vector?

Comment: Yes. Check the definition of linear combination. Indeed, part of the point of PCA etc is that the coefficients *do* depend on the vector on the left-hand side. I also found this strangely circular, the first time I heard about it.